# How to start a child process of a daemon process which itself is not daemon

Tags: c, linux, unix, daemon

I found an [interesting problem](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/20869/) on the net. I'll reproduce it here for reference.

> I'm writing a `daemon` process to execute programs and then restart
>   them if they exit with a status of something other than
>   `EXIT_SUCCESS`; but these programs will probably not want to be daemon
>   processes themselves. If I use `fork()` and then call `execv()` will
>   the new child process be a daemon process too?
>
> I tried running firefox and it didn't work.   So, in which case, how
>   can I start the child processes as normal processes?

The solutions offered in that site somehow doesn't convince me. Any ideas?

Comment: Copied from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/20869/). Please refrain from copying text verbatim from other sites and posting it in SO

Comment: And there is no nice solution

Comment: You could have indicated the same in your post quoting the source.

Comment: If you copy a doubt, this not means that you also copied the solution. I was not understanding the solution so why not use SO!!

Comment: I am not discouraging you from getting things found on other sites clarified in SO, but its just that you should paste the data **verbatim** which makes SO look like a clone site. Attributing the source is very important when you are reproducing something verbatim

Comment: Now can you answer? Pls.

Comment: I have the exact same doubt so - verbatim

Comment: I've rephrased your question to reflect your intention. Good luck! -1 wasn't from me. And as the question is a good one, I am +1 ing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by daemon process you mean the file descriptors of stdin, stdout and stderr are not connected to any tty or pts, then yes.  So just opening *something* for stdin, stdout and stderr should work.

However, you should have tried it yourself first, firefox (here) opens perfectly with stdin, stdout and stderr redirected to `/dev/null`.  I think the main thing is that you call `execv()` or `execve()` and keep the `DISPLAY` variable.

*Edit*
If your asking how to reconnect to the original descriptor destinations then there's at least no portable solution.  Obviously you can't reconnect to a pipe.  You can however reconnect (under linux at least) to the tty/pts you came from, or even the file (using the `/proc` filesystem and `readlink()`).  You will have to guess the "seek" though (e.g. if the original command was `foo 2>> bar`).

Comment: And what about the different session created when we made the daemon

Comment: that's not a problem, well, in case of firefox, they just want some i18n and the `DISPLAY` variables

Comment: The standard procedure is *re-aquire the terminal*: open /dev/tty and dup2() it over fd{012}. The process group is different stuff.

Comment: i must admit, i haven't tried the example as is, i've created my own daemon just by your description and then tried to `execv()` firefox in a fork thereof

Comment: @wildplasser: that will connect to *a* tty, not necessarily the one you started with.  But depending on what you're trying to achieve that might be the way to go.

Comment: (at least in linux) the /dev/tty entry points to the tty of the *curren* process. issuing `cat file.c >/dev/tty` results in the file being echoed on any PTY. I don't know what happens what happens to the /dev/tty once the process has detached from its TTY. I guess it will still be there (since it probably relies on *current*) This stuff is all in Stevens's APUE, IIRC.